# How to Click on the each individual position using base adapter

Tags: java, android

I am using the base adapter , i have list which contains list with the text view  (means left side sent items and below to that ,right side received items, i want to click on the each position in the list to perform replying the messaging .

Please suggest me how do i perform the function on clicking the listitem

Below is the code ,which i am using

class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
     ViewHolder viewHolder;
     LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Constant_Variables.Sms_Status_list.size();
        }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }



     @Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_row, null);

             viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

             viewHolder.sms_from_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_from_txtview);
             viewHolder.sms_to_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_sendto_txtview);

         }
         else
         {
             viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }


         viewHolder.sms_from_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


         if(Constant_Variables.Sms_Status_list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Twilioresponse_Utils.sms_sent))
         {
             viewHolder.sms_from_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             viewHolder.sms_to_row.setText("Sent: "+Constant_Variables.Sms_from_list.get(position));

         }
         else if(Constant_Variables.Sms_Status_list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Twilioresponse_Utils.sms_received))
         {
             viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             viewHolder.sms_from_row.setText("Received: "+Constant_Variables.Sms_to_list.get(position));
         }
         else
         {
             viewHolder.sms_from_row.setText("Message in queued.");
             viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }


         convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


         return convertView;
     }

     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

         if(l.callOnClick()== true)
         {
             Log.i("the Item clicked is at position : ", ""+ position);
         }

         else
         {
             Log.i("the Item not clicked is at position : ","the Item not clicked is at position" );
         }
     }
 }
```

Below is the XML code which i am using

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sms_from_txtview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="From" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sms_sendto_txtview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="To" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Regards
Amrinder Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is onItemClickListener in android, you can use that

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlist);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // @todo
    }
});
```

For individual view in you list item, you can always add click listener in getView method.

Comment: Please read question carefully @Amrinder want individual click views which are in single listview item using this it will listening for whole item not for child view

Comment: @Pratik : he has said :"Please suggest me how do i perform the function on clicking the listitem" and that is the reason i have given this solution. Please tell me a reson for downvote

Comment: Thank you newBee,its help me in clicking the position ,one more question on this ,there is  a list of receiving messages ,i want to reply on that particular receive message in the list ,how could i fetch the details from that list of that particular messages to which i want to reply .Please help me on this too

Comment: @Amrinder, For that you can create a helper class with getter-setter, store a position in a arraylist and in onItemClick compare the list item position with your saved position. I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Implement click listener for both when you initialize that view

```
viewHolder.sms_from_row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        // Todo thing
    }
});
viewHolder.sms_to_row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        // Todo thing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right just add the click listener below this.

```
 viewHolder.sms_from_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_from_txtview);
 viewHolder.sms_to_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_sendto_txtview);
```

Below this add click listener like this.

```
viewHolder.sms_from_row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

    viewHolder.sms_to_row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Hope it help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write on item click on textview

```
   @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagelist_row, null);

         viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

         viewHolder.sms_from_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_from_txtview);
         viewHolder.sms_to_row=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sms_sendto_txtview);

viewHolder.sms_from_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    });
     }
     else
     {
         viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }


     viewHolder.sms_from_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


     if(Constant_Variables.Sms_Status_list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Twilioresponse_Utils.sms_sent))
     {
         viewHolder.sms_from_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         viewHolder.sms_to_row.setText("Sent: "+Constant_Variables.Sms_from_list.get(position));

     }
     else if(Constant_Variables.Sms_Status_list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(Twilioresponse_Utils.sms_received))
     {
         viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         viewHolder.sms_from_row.setText("Received: "+Constant_Variables.Sms_to_list.get(position));
     }
     else
     {
         viewHolder.sms_from_row.setText("Message in queued.");
         viewHolder.sms_to_row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }


     convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


     return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: Thank You Muraliganesan,it worked ,but could you suggest me in fetching the details of that particular clicked item ,i am unable to solve this thing .I able to click ,but not able to fetch the details of that particular click on the received item.Please help me in this too dear

Comment: @Amrinder You can set the information you need from a view by using `setTag(Object method)` for the view. Suppose you want to get the index of a msg showed in a text view, set it as the tag for the textview as `textview.setTag(index)`.

Comment: @Supreethks: i could not able to get the information of that particular click event which i am clicking in the list view with setting the tags.please help

Comment: Now i get the values :) on clicking

Comment: Inside `onclick` put this code u you will get clicked item `position` `Constant_Variables.Sms_to_list.get(position));` @Amrinder

Answer (score 0):

**When clicked on list**
[image: When Click on List]


**Clicked on Delete icon**
[image: when click on delete icon]

**here is the code you can refer:**

```
    public class CaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;
        ArrayList<PojoClass> list;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CaseAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PojoClass> list)
        {
            this.context=context;
            this.list=list;
            inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
             ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null)
            {

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_screen, parent,false);            
                holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);

            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            holder.caseNumber.setText(list.get(position).getCaseNo());
            holder.state.setText(list.get(position).getState());
            holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Toast.makeText(context, "record clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v=(View) v.getParent();//utilizing the View object...or we can use new view object
                    //View view=(View)v.getParent();//this one also we can use...but instead of v object you need to use view object;

                    TextView number=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_case_number);
                    InfoDb db=new InfoDb(context);//using for remove record from database
                    db.open();

                    if(db.removeRecord(number.getText().toString()))
                    {
list.remove(position);
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Record Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  CaseAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }else
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Record not Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    db.close();
                }
            });

            return row;
        }


        public class ViewHolder{

            TextView state,caseNumber,date;
            ImageView delete;

            public ViewHolder(View v){
                state=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_State);
                caseNumber=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_case_number);
                date=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_date);
                delete=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView_Delete);


            }


        }

    }
```